# How to run PHP script from cron to parse a site with protection (domain name checking)? How to run PHP script in cron from this domain name?

Tags: php, cron

I have a site with installed (provided by other site) widgets (included JavaScript codes).

These widgets require specific domain name (domain name of my site). Being installed on another site, these widgets do not work. I want to periodically parse these widgets on my site. But when I try to do it with php script, runned from cron, I see only an error like "invalid domain name".

Can I imitate running from real site, not from cron? Headers, low-level http requests? I don't know, what mechanism of domain name checking used in widgets. Is there any ready to use solutions for same problems? Libs, frameworks, etc?

P.S. cron script runs from the same shared hosting account where my site with widgets placed.

P.P.S. The owner of widget system is myself. I can add other sites to pass the domain name checking in widget system admin panel, but I can't to add "cron job" instead of a domain name there).

```
$url = 'https://example.com/api/widget/checkWidget'; 
$buttonId = 'the button id is here'; 
$data = json_encode(['ButtonId' => $buttonId]); 

$curl = curl_init($url); 

curl_setopt_array($curl, [ 
CURLOPT_POST => 1, 
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data, 
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, 
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [ 
'Content-Type: application/json', 
'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data), 
], 
CURLOPT_RESOLVE => ['site where the widgets placed and worked fine'], 
]); 

$result = curl_exec($curl); 

var_dump($result);
```

But only thing I see instead of widget data is something like `'{\"Result\":null,\"ErrCode\":20001,\"ErrMsg\":\"The site is invalid\"}'`

Comment: You need to post some code that shows what you're doing and where the domain name is checked.

Comment: How are you running JavaScript widgets from a PHP script?

Comment: " I don't know, what mechanism of domain name checking used in widgets" then "The owner of widget system is myself" I dont see how both statements can be true

Comment: Please see [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: @IdontDownVote
I ordered development the widget system for 3rd party IT company. The system created long time ago, it isn't under development now.

Comment: @Barmar
I don't. I just try to call API from cron script to get widget data like the widgets themselves request them being installed on the site.

Comment: So the API is doing this check, not the widget itself? It's probably checking the `Origin` header.

Comment: @Barmar I added some code from cron script.

Comment: Without knowing how `checkWidget` checks the domain name, it's still really hard to answer this.

Answer (score 1):

The widget probably checks the `Origin` header to determine the domain name of the web page that's using it. So try adding that header:

```
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [ 
'Content-Type: application/json', 
'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data), 
'Origin: https://www.yourdomain.com'
],
```

I doubt you really need the `CURLOPT_RESOLVE` option. That's used to resolve the hostname in `$url` if it can't be found using normal DNS, or to override DNS lookups (similar to the way `/etc/hosts` is used).

Comment: Thanks, but result output is the same.

Comment: Then we need more information about how the widget is checking the domain.

Comment: It's not like this is a standard, built-in operation with a well known solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to my hosting support: the solution is `CURLOPT_REFERER => 'https://test-med-status.cf'`